# Display multiple elements in a custom listview

Tags: java, android, listview

Currently I have a custom list view that I want to display a picture a name and a subject in each row. The edit texts in each row are only displaying the name and not a subject

```
public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    BookAdapter(Context context, String[] books, String[] subjects)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.bookrow, books);


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        LayoutInflater booksinflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = booksinflater.inflate(R.layout.bookrow, parent, false);

        String singleBookItem = getItem(position);
        String singleBookSubject = getItem(position);
        TextView bookName = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.BookName);
        ImageView bookImage = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.bookimage);
        TextView bookSubject = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.BookSubject);


        bookName.setText(singleBookItem);
        bookImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.matter_of_fact);
        bookSubject.setText(singleBookSubject);

        return customView;
    }
}
```

I understand that it has something to do with the enter code here         `super(context, R.layout.bookrow, book);` but how do I change this to include both book and subject?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:weightSum="1"
              android:id="@+id/layout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/bookimage"
        android:src="@drawable/matter_of_fact"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/BookName"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/BookSubject"
            android:padding="30dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show your R.layout.bookrow xml

Comment: @FabioVenturiPastor added it there

Comment: What do you mean by edit texts? I see two TextViews.

Comment: @greenapps I meant TextView sorry I got mixed up

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
    String singleBookItem = getItem(position);
    String singleBookSubject = getItem(position);
```

You are setting the same text for both: subject and book name.
Create some additional method which returns the subject...

Something like:

```
@Override
// Return the book name for that position
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return books[position];
}

// Return the subject for that position
private String getSubject(int position) {
    return subjects[position];
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater booksinflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = booksinflater.inflate(R.layout.bookrow, parent, false);
    }

    String singleBookItem = getItem(position);
    String singleBookSubject = getSubject(position);

    ...

    bookName.setText(singleBookItem);
    bookImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.matter_of_fact);
    bookSubject.setText(singleBookSubject);

    return customView;
}
```